# Get most occuring text string after comma, use for whatever purposes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to grab the most occuring text in this code below after the "," in this HTML with Jquery. In this case, the text would return "Bothell". How would I go about doing this?

```
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bellevue</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Kirkland</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Monroe</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
```

Tried this code from a user below, doesn't work:

```
 let As = document.querySelectorAll("a.address");
let towns = new Map();
for(let a of As)
{
  let town = a.textContent.split(',')[1].trim()
  if(towns.has(town))
  {
    towns.set(town, towns.get(town)+1) 
  }
  else
  {
    towns.set(town, 1);
  }
}
let most = [...towns.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0];
if ($("a.address").length) {
            var signupText = (most);
            $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching ' + signupText + ' real estate.');
        } else {
            var signupText = '';
             $(".rg-modal-signup h2").text('Keep searching for your dream home.');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do multiple thing here:

1. Extract the name
2. Count occurrences
3. Get the one with highest result.

Here's a quick code you can use based on the input above. Note that this doesn't consider multiple comma occurrences, but I think you can already adjust what's needed next. :)

```
const data = `<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bellevue</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Kirkland</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Monroe</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>`;

const anchors = data.split('\n');

const getName = (row) => {
    const index = row.indexOf(',');
    const commaOffset = 2;
    const suffixOffset = 4;
    const length = row.length;
    return row.substring(index + commaOffset, length - suffixOffset);
}

const names = anchors.map(getName);

const counts = names.reduce((group, name) => {
    if (!group[name]) {
        group[name] = 1;
    } else {
        group[name]++;
    }

    return group;
}, {});

const entries = Object.entries(counts);
const sorted = entries.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
const hightestCount = sorted.shift();


console.log(hightestCount)
```

This should give you:

```
[ 'Bothell', 4 ]
```

You know what to do with it after. Best of luck!

Comment: Wow thanks so much. What if there is a ton of these A Tags though? I want to be able to count within as many A tags show up on the DOM. Thank you!!!

Comment: This should work fine with that. Please note that if you are using jQuery, you can pull all texts using `.text()` property. So simply get `$('a')` all the anchors, loop through them to get `.text()` into an array then use the code snippet I have above. :)

Comment: *"loop through them to get .text()*" - use jquery .map

Comment: I have never used jquery map. So not sure how to go about that... I'm a novice still. Thanks for the feedback though, somewhere to start!

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a map of counts of town names, then sort them, descending, by count and extract the first element.

If you're expecting there to be other elements you want to ignore within the link text, you can remove those by cloning the element, iterating through the children and removing each one from the clone. Using a clone will keep the page looking the same.

```js
let As = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

let towns = new Map();

for(let a of As)
{
  let aClone = a.cloneNode(true);
  [...aClone.children].forEach(kid => aClone.removeChild(kid));
  let town = aClone.textContent.split(',')[1].trim()
  if(towns.has(town))
  {
    towns.set(town, towns.get(town)+1) 
  }
  else
  {
    towns.set(town, 1);
  }
}

let most = [...towns.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0]

console.log(most);
```

```html
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bellevue</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Kirkland</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Monroe</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, Bothell</a>
<a href="/search/details/50/1/" class="address">9207 Odin Wy, <span>Monroe, </span> Bothell</a>
```

Comment: I used your code with a slight change. Original didn't work as well. I pasted the code in the original comment.

Comment: What was the problem you had? you seem to have changed your question from what it originally was.

Comment: I actually got this to work, but it returns "Bothell,4". I'm fairly new to this, how would I just make it show "Bothell" instead of adding the count?

Comment: `most[0]` will give the town name

Comment: Thank you. Also, if there is a span within the 'a' element, how do I make this code ignore the span text?

Comment: @KevinBoroumand I have updated the answer to accommodate that.